# Android LoopJ's HTTP client

Tags: android, loopj

I'm using LoopJ to connect my app to a web service.

I make multiple ws request using AsyncHttpClient  in a for loop ( i must send them in a loop ; i can not send them all at one )

For each resond that i recive i must modify a specific TextView in my app. ( the number of textview's that i have equal number of ws requests)

Is there a way to bind some information (string) on each and every new AsyncHttpClient() that i make and retrive this information on onSuccess?

Comment: What do you mean by bind information ?

Comment: some how add/store to that ws request the id of the edittext that i need to change info when onSuccess is called.  For ex : i could have 5 edittext. I make a for loop ( 5 iteretions ) that generate 5 separete ws request. And i need when on onSuccess is called to know what edittext i need to modify. I can not send the id as a parameter because the ws is not in my control.

Comment: You can pass ID to each web service call which gives you back same id in response

Comment: can you please show me how? in a code

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go in the following way

```
int count=0;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           count++;
           new Netcall().execute();
          //call assync task for first timehere
}


    private static class Netcall extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

             //your code http call
}



    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

               count++;
             if(count<=numberoftimesyouwanttoexecute)
           new Netcall().execute();
}

}
```